# Mirror add class to ul li in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tested this code. but there have some error. i am also attachment with [JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PgrE.png)  file what my need exactly please suggestion me.

```js
 $('.list ul li a').click(function() {
   $('.list li a').removeClass("ad");
   $(this).addClass("ad");
 });
```

```css
.ad{background-color:green;color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
<h4>A</h4>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"> list 1 </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#"> list 2 </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#"> list 3 </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
<h4>B</h4>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"> list 1 </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#"> list 2 </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#"> list 3 </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? instead of image you should explain

Comment: http://justdemo.site/automadoc/ (here url )

Comment: What i understand is using `$(this)` => `$(this).removeClass("ad");`

Comment: if i select A > ul li then auto select B > ul li, means both of select at a time

Comment: Do you mean: If select `list 1` from `A`, automatically select `list 1` from `B` ?

Comment: yes Mr.X i need same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you must create a link between `A` children and `B` children, you can set a `data` attribute for example `data-id` then find the equals with:

```
 $('.list li a[data-id="'+dataId+'"]').addClass('ad');
```

```js
$('.list ul li a').click(function() {
  var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('.list ul li a').removeClass('ad');
  $('.list li a[data-id="'+dataId+'"]').addClass('ad');
});
```

```css
.ad {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <h4>A</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="list-1"> list 1 </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="list-2"> list 2 </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="list-3"> list 3 </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <h4>B</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="list-1"> list 1 </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="list-2"> list 2 </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="list-3"> list 3 </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Update:** on your website, use something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.btn-nav-main').each(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      var dataSlide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
      $('.btn-nav-main').removeClass('gg');
      $('.btn-nav-main data-slide["' + dataSlide + '"]').addClass('gg');
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: hello Mr. x Second thing is its solve 50% but 50% is left, please check the site http://justdemo.site/automadoc/ i want active both class on scroll, is it posible??

Comment: yes @Mr. x you are right and  i am change 'data-id' to 'data-slide'

Comment: @Gaurav So you need to put this code (i mean answer) to where your scroll function add active class to top nav. you did this?

Comment: your previews code is onclick function working fine, and i need same thing on scroll,

Comment: @Gaurav Look, in your website you have a top nav, right? when you scroll down or up, it add class to top nav based on each section. okay? so you need add this code (answer) where you used scroll function.

Comment: @Gaurav okay, let me check

Comment: @Gaurav check updated answer. but due i have not access to your website it's hard to write right code! so i give you a logic, follow this and make fix on your web.

Comment: @Gaurav I recommend you to post this problem as new question.